# jQuery Draggable plugin integration with Views 3

Tags: views, javascript, users

I want draggable and sortable contents by admin. So, installed jQuery UI and put this code in my main.js:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".panels-flexible-region" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    $( "#makyaj .views-row" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: ".panels-flexible-region",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

Yes, it works. But i want use this option only admin user. Whether View Sort Type: Jquery Draggable and qhat sets the admin users so they can see it.

Is it possible? Can i integration Views and jQuery UI Draggable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something along these lines in a custom module...

```
function mymodule_init() {
  global $user;

  if ($user->uid==1) { // super/admin user, add role based logic if needed or desired
    drupal_add_js('path/to/admin-only.js');
  }
}
```

...where 'path/to/admin-only.js' is a file containing JS you want added only for your admin/super user.  Look into [drupal_add_js()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't exactly what you asked for, but have you considered using the [draggable views](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) module? It does what you aim to do without you having to code anything.